# Проверка подключения к интернету в среде делфи

Tags: delphi-7

Я использую функцию `InternetGetConnectedState`, но когда я отключаю интернет она продолжает возвращать мне `True`. В связи с этим возникает ошибка. Как быть?

Comment: Читать справку по функции.


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была в том, что функция возвращает `true`, потому что, есть активный модем. В эту функцию не следует передавать параметр `Internet_Connection_Modem`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckInetLink(URL: string): byte;
begin
  Result := CheckInetConnect;
  if URL <> '' then
    if Result <> 0 then
      if not CheckUrl(URL) then
        Result := 0;
end;
```

Если не передать URL, то просто проверит соединение (но бывает что соединение есть, а интернета нет), а если передать URL то проверит его доступность (это более надежный вариант). Лучше передавать URL например на Google или Yandex.

Comment: Спасибо, Работает замечательно, но я хотел разобраться именно с указанной функцией.